# How to pass runtime params from LINQPad script to the C# class that runs it

Tags: c#, linqpad

While compiling and running a LINQPad script from within a C# class, I need to extract stuff from the script to the C# code that compiled and ran it, **during runtime**. what's the best way to achive this?

Specifically I'd like to show a progress bar on a GUI, that will be updated from within the script.

```
public static int ScriptExecutionProgress = 0;
void SomeMethod()
{
   LINQPad.ObjectModel.QueryCompilation compiledScript = LINQPad.Util.Compile("SomeScript.linq");
   LINQPad.ObjectModel.QueryExecuter exec = 
   compiledScript.Run(LINQPad.QueryResultFormat.Text);

   // I can get a return value and read all the dumped obejcts 
   // when the "CompiledScript" concludes it's run, 
   // but I how do I display progress int (or string) that is updated in the script when it's still running??      
}
```

Comment: This is not currently supported - LINQPad does not expose any Remoting or other communication mechanism between the parent and child query.

Comment: Thanks Joe, care to post as an anwer, so that I can accept?